# Apache PIG: Issue with UNION

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Apache PIG: I have two data sets X,Y with same schema. 
X is having 222 no.of.records,Y is having 70 records.
I need to combine two, means vertically add two data sets. If I use UNION the problem is output is having more than the number of records expected. 
That is on Z = UNION X,Y; is having 888 records. 
can any one give suggestions.

Example Code:

```
UI_INFO = filter LOGS BY hotel_book.step == 'UI_INFO';
LOGS_ITINERARY = filter LOGS BY hotel_book.step == 'CREATE_ITINERARY';
LOGS_JOINED = join UI_INFO by header.itinerary_id LEFT OUTER , LOGS_ITINERARY by header.itinerary_id;
LOGS_BOOK_COL1 = FOREACH LOGS_JOINED {
CURRENCY = LOGS_ITINERARY::hotel_book.itinerary.hotel.rooms.currency;
GENERATE UI_INFO::header.date_time AS date_time,
LOGS_ITINERARY::hotel_book.pay_at_hotel AS pay_at_hotel,
UI_INFO::header.referrer AS referrer,
UI_INFO::hotel_book.step AS stage,
FLATTEN( (IsEmpty(CURRENCY) ? TOBAG('unknown') : CURRENCY) ) AS currency;
};
REMAINING_LOGS = FILTER LOGS BY (hotel_book.step == 'CREATE_ITINERARY' OR hotel_book.step == 'PROVISIONAL_BOOK') 
LOGS_BOOK_COL2 = FOREACH REMAINING_LOGS {
CURRENCY = hotel_book.itinerary.hotel.rooms.currency;
GENERATE header.date_time AS date_time,
hotel_book.pay_at_hotel AS pay_at_hotel,
header.referrer AS referrer,
hotel_book.step AS stage,
FLATTEN( (IsEmpty(CURRENCY) ? TOBAG('unknown') : CURRENCY) ) AS currency;
};
LOGS_BOOK_COL = UNION LOGS_BOOK_COL1,LOGS_BOOK_COL2;
```

Comment: Are you sure about the counts?

Comment: Yes @madhu, I tested many times.

Comment: What is actually happening which data set is getting duplicated X or Y

Comment: how can I say which data set is getting duplicated.When I run UNION on X,Y , result set rows should be equal to total rows from X ,Y. But it is giving more records. This is problem with UNION ,my datasets have so large no.of.bags and tuples.

Comment: @Vinodh : after union, can you perform a DISTINCT on Z alias and let us know if the count is coming to 292 ?

Comment: Can we see some code for this so we can better help?

Comment: @MikePone, Hi Added the code at the end of question.

Comment: Have you verified the counts of LOGS_BOOK_COL1 and LOGS_BOOK_COL2 just before the union?

Comment: yes,  I mentioned X here is nothing but LOGS_BOOK_COL1,Y is LOGS_BOOK_COL2    @MikePone

Comment: Hey, I missed the count in the flow some where, this is not the issue with UNION.